# Find all combinations that gives the result A[i]+B[j]=C[k] with 3 arrays at O[n^2]

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, combinations, equation

There are 3 arrays, every array has a size of `N`. Find the combinations that give `A[i]+B[j]=C[k]` at only O[n^2].

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: i'd prefer java

Comment: For answering the *programming* question, it would be useful if you provide some code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Question was later modified to ask specifically for an implementation in Java. The algorithm and explanation in Python remain valid, but I've also added Java implementation below.

---

Use a [hashmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (or a set) to test for existence in `C` with time complexity `O(1)` (on average). Then all you need is to iterate over all pairs `(a,b) | a <- A, b <- B`, for a total time complexity of `O(n^2)`.

For example, in **Python** you could do it like this:

```
c = set(C)
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if a + b in c:
            print a, b, a + b
```

Quick test:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> B = [3,4,5]
>>> C = [1,4,7]
>>> c = set(C)
>>> for a in A:
...     for b in B:
...         if a + b in c:
...             print a, b, a + b
... 
1 3 4
2 5 7
3 4 7
```

Or, a shorter version with a list comprehension:

```
>>> c = set(C)
>>> [(a,b,a+b) for a in A for b in B if a+b in c]
[(1, 3, 4), (2, 5, 7), (3, 4, 7)]
```

---

The **Java** implementation is essentially the same. The key observation is to use `java.util.HashSet` for checking if the sum `A[i]+B[j]` is present in the array `C`:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

class Pairs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] A = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
        Integer[] B = new Integer[]{3,4,5};
        Integer[] C = new Integer[]{1,4,7};

        HashSet<Integer> c = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
            c.add(C[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
                if (c.contains(A[i] + B[j])) {
                    System.out.format("%d %d %d%n", A[i], B[j], A[i]+B[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is it not taking another 'n' iterations when searching in c?

Comment: Because `c` is a hashmap (set), and lookup complexity in [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is `O(1)`, i.e. in constant time.

Comment: Python is such a beautiful language. I ought to learn it - soon.

Comment: It sure has its moments, especially for such a short and sweet problems like this one.

Comment: various operations in hash have constant _average_ time, worst case is linear

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler problem: given two arrays and a number find all combinations from the arrays which give sum=number. It can be solved in O(n).

We can use its solution as part of solution for the larger one:

(I'm assuming that all elements are different - it simplifies things a bit)

```
sort(A)
sort(B)
sort(C)
for(int indexC=0;indexC<N;++indexC)
    int indexA=0
    int indexB=N-1
    while(indexA<0)
        //find all combinations in A,B with sum=C[indexC]
        int sum=A[indexA]+B[indexB]
        if(sum==C[indexC])
            OutputCombination(indexA,indexB,indexC)
        if(sum<C[indexC])
            ++indexA
        else if(sum>C[indexC])
            --indexB
        else
            ++indexA
            --indexB
```